# Apache root <Directory> directive override

Tags: apache, easyphp

Firstly, I am beginner with Apache configuration so sorry if for any of you it will look trivial.

I have simple website hosted in one of my home server. I am using easyphp for hosting. The problem is that when I look from my development PC website can't show images because my Apache config is not working. I have such config:

```
<Directory />
 Order Allow,Deny
 AllowOverride none
 Deny from All
</Directory>
<Directory /projects/web>
 Order Allow,Deny
 Allow from All
</Directory>
```

My website content is at */projects/web* from Apache docs I understand that any new container below should override the root container, but in my case the content is only accessible when I set root container to Allow.

Could you tell what I am doing wrong here?